# How can I define an input for a component?

Tags: angular, input, components

I defined an input for a component such as:  **@Input() person: Person** but I encountered this error: *property 'person' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor*!!!. even, the Person model has been imported. this error occurs for any type of input variable such as string, number and so on...
when I change the type of input variable to 'any', the problem is solved!
how can define an input with its type for a component without above error?

Comment: pls show us the component because I think you are trying to add the input outside the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havent shared your code so not sure where you are adding `@Input()` decorator, here is the working example how to add `@Input()` decorator in the component.

You can check the implementation and match it with what you have done.

**Update after @Eliseo comment:**
In Angular 12 you have a `strictPropertyInitialization`, you can use the "Definite Assignment Assertion", (add an ! when declare input) `@Input() person!: Person;` or give a value by defect `@Input() person: Person=new Person()`

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-person',
 templateUrl: './person.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./person.component.scss'],
})

export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() person!: Person;

 constructor() {}

 ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Comment: In Angular 12 you has a strictPropertyInitialization, you can use the "Definite Assignment Assertion", (add an `!` when declare input) `@Input() person!: Person;` or give a value by defect `@Input() person: Person=new Person();` if is a class or `@Input() person: Person={} as Person;` if is an interface

Comment: Hi dear, the "@Input() person!: Person;" statement worked well... thank a lot

Comment: @R.Nourmandi glad to hear, you can accept & upvote the answer it will help others.